# Get every slug from entry for each language

Tags: url, language

For the `robot.txt` file, I want to get every URI from the entries for every language. Right now it just gets the URI from one language.

```
{% set crawledEntries = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: crawlSites, field: "entryCrawler" },
    order: "sortOrder"
}) %}

{% for entry in crawledEntries %}
    Disallow: /{{ entry.uri }}
{% endfor %}
```

This now loops just through one locale.

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

```
{% set crawledEntries = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: crawlSites, field: "entryCrawler" },
    order: "sortOrder"
}) %}

{% set otherLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds()|without(craft.locale) %}

{% for entry in crawledEntries %}
    Disallow: /{{ entry.uri }}
    {% for locale in otherLocales %}
        {% set entryL = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale).first() %}

        {% if entryL %}
            Disallow: /{{locale}}/{{ entryL.uri }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```